# If $f(0) > g(0)$, and $\exists N > 0$ such that if $k\geq N$ then $f(k)>g(k)$ and $f,g$ are monotonic increasing, is $f(x)>g(x)$ $\forall x\geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, monotone-functions

Suppose we have two monotonically increasing functions $f,g$ with $f(0)>g(0)$ and the existence of a finite $N>0$ such that if $k\geq N$ then $f(k) > g(k)$

I now want to show that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all values of $x\geq 0$. What extra criteria would I need? I know that with this alone its not enough to prove it because, which I was able to visualize just by drawing a simple picture.

The obvious answer is that if $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ for all $x\geq 0$ then we are good, but I was looking for a more lax condition.

My intuition tells me that if I can show that the derivatives themselves are monotonic then that is sufficient because we will not have any locations in which $f$ slows down and dips below $g$ and then increases at a faster rate to become greater again, however how can I write this out in a tight way?

Comment: It is not sufficient that $f'$ and $g'$ are increasing: Consider $f(x) = x^2 +0.1$  and $g(x) = x$ on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @MartinR what if the derivatives are monotonically decreasing?

Comment: Doesn't work either: $f(x) = x + 0.1$, $g(x) = \sqrt x$.

Comment: What derivative criteria would be required for the claim to be true?

Comment: @wjmccann I'd be very surprised if any such condition exists other than $f' > g'$ or things that turn out to imply that.

Comment: Hm I assume that any info about $f''$,$g''$ also wouldn't be of much help?

Comment: Unless $f,g$ are continuous, the information $f(k)>g(k)$ tells us absolutely nothing about $f(x),g(x), x<N$. So if we assume they are continuous, it all boils down to "[in the interval $(0,N)$] $f$ and $g$ do not intersect each other"

Comment: The two functions are continuous, do you have an idea on how to show they do not intersect?